# Sum of series $\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{(n+1){}^2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to solve this sum?$$\sqrt{1+\frac1{1^2}+\frac1{2^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{1+\frac1{19^2}+\frac1{20^2}}$$
I assumed it to be a sum of $\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n^2} + \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}}$ but It complicates the powers and I am unable to factorise further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1+\dfrac1{n^2}+\dfrac1{(n+1)^2}=\dfrac{n^2+(n+1)^2+(n^2+n)^2}{n^2(n+1)^2}=\dfrac{n^4+2n^3+3n^2+2n+1}{(n^2+n)^2}$$

$n^4+2n^3+3n^2+2n+1=(n^2)^2+2n^2\cdot1+2n\cdot1+(n)^2+1^2+2n^2\cdot n=(n^2+n+1)^2$

Now $$\dfrac{n^2+n+1}{n(n+1)}=1+\dfrac1{n(n+1)}=1+\dfrac{n+1-n}{n(n+1)}=?$$

**See also**: [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Comment: $$\left(1+\dfrac1n-\dfrac1{n+1}\right)^2=1+\dfrac1{n^2}+\dfrac1{(n+1)^2}+\dfrac2n-\dfrac2{n+1}-\dfrac2{n(n+1)}$$


$\dfrac1n-\dfrac1{n+1}-\dfrac1{n(n+1)}=\dfrac{n+1-n-1}{n(n+1)}=0$

Comment: $$\left(\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b+\dfrac1c\right)^2=\dfrac1{a^2}+\dfrac1{b^2}+\dfrac1{c^2}$$  will hold if $$a+b+c=0$$ Here $a=1,b=n,c=?$